# Splist Url string after character using php

Tags: php

I have the url from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as `/a/b/c/d/e`

I want to get the string `/a/b/c` via php. Is there a way to use the split function and split after `/d'?

Comment: Which pattern is behind this cut of the url?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't include the `http://example.com` part of the URL, does it? It should only hold `/a/b/c/d/e`

Comment: Correct. Please see my updated question

Comment: Split by "/" and re-concatenate the first three elements....

Comment: Lots of ways via simple string manipulation: `echo substr("/a/b/c/d/e", 0, strpos("/a/b/c/d/e", "/d"));` or some variant of array operation like `list($first, ) = explode("/d", "/a/b/c/d/e");` which places your string into `$first`.

Comment: [Lots of similar examples here...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+before+substring)

Answer (score 0):

```
$stringtoprocess='/a/b/c/d/e';
$mypieces=explode('/', $stringtoprocess);

echo $mypieces[1];   //a
echo $mypieces[2];   //b
echo $mypieces[3];   //c
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below looks for the regex pattern stored in $pattern in $url, then it stores the matches in $matches. Keep in mind the $matches[0] is the whole string being matched, in this case $url. Give it a try:

```
$url = "/a/b/c/d/e";
$pattern = '/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)/';
preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: On Stack overflow, it's recommended to not post code only answers. Please explain what your code is doing

Comment: Oh, ok. The code above looks for the regex pattern stored in $pattern in $url, then it stores the matches in $matches. Keep in mind the $matches[0] is the whole string being matched, in this case $url.

Comment: It belongs in your answer and not a comment. Whenever you post an answer try to explain it. Not everyone will understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = '/a/b/c/d/e';
$array = explode('/',$url);
$new_url = '/'.$array[1].'/'.$array[2].'/'.$array[3];
```